# My custom Python logger function doesn't work with OpenCV

Tags: python, logging, path, working-directory

I have a custom logger function for my program that logs what was done by whom and at what time (it's a facial recognition software/database editor for a multi-locker safe).:

```
def logger(what, who, log_file):
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write('Zdarzenie: {} Kto: {} Kiedy: {}\n'.format(what, who, dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Which works perfectly fine in most cases. However when I call this function while using OpenCV it does nothing.
It is called correctly (I had some prints to check) but nothing gets written to log.txt file.
Also if the log.txt file doesn't exist it's not created when I call logger() here. It gets created fine if I call the function anywhere else in my program.
I'm guessing it has to do something with OpenCV "blocking" Python's ability to open a file (?)

```
def recognize():

    face_recognizer.read(os.path.join(katalog_glowny, 'rozpoznawacz.yml'))

    test_img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(katalog_glowny, 'identyfikacja/identyfikacja.jpg'))
    img = test_img.copy()

    face, rect = face_detect(img)

    if face is None:
        message_box('Błąd!', 'Błąd! Nie wykryto twarzy. Spróbuj ponownie.', QMessageBox.Information)
        logger('Nieudane otwarcie skrytki', 'n/d', 'log.txt')
    else:
        label, uncertainty = face_recognizer.predict(twarz)
        try:
            recognized_user = sesja.query(Osoba).filter(Osoba.katalog == os.path.join('test', 's{}'.format(label))).one()  # zamiast test przekazywać folder obejmujący jako argument przy wywołaniu funkcji
        except IndexError as e:
            print('IndexError {}'.format(e))
        else:
            podpis_tekst = '{}, np: {}'.format(recognized_user.login, str(uncertainty))
            draw_rect(img, rect)
            draw_text(img, podpis_tekst, rect[0], rect[1] - 5)
            cv2.imshow("Prediction ", img)

            print('DEBUG {} {}'.format(recognized_user.skrytka, recognized_user.login))
            logger('Otwarcie skrytki {}'.format(recognized_user.skrytka), recognized_user.login, 'log.txt')
            message_box('Otwieranie skrytki', 'Witaj {} - otworzy się skrytka {}'.format(recognized_user.imie_nazwisko, recognized_user.skrytka), QMessageBox.Information)

        return img
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. May I add I'm just learning Python and I'm an absolute beginner. Any help is highly appreciated.

I added some print statements to the logger() function to check if it's called properly and it apparently is - the print statements worked as expected. However nothing got written to the log.txt file.
This function works perfectly in other places in my program.

**######### EDIT #########**

[klaus-d's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) comment is the solution here.

> Might be a working directory problem. Have you tried using the full path for the file?

It turned out that the log.txt file was created but in a different directory.

So, making it a full path like:
`'C:\Users\artur\[...]\log.txt'`
should fix the problem.

Still, to avoid Python's allergy to Windows file paths I just created a variable at the beggining of the program to hold the log file location:
`log = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'log.txt')` which fixed the problem.

Comment: Might be a working directory problem. Have you tried using the full path for the file?

Comment: Thank you for your answear. Oh my God that was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Yes, thank you. However Klaus's response has already solved my problem :)